# Open CSV/TXT file from DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, csv, android-intent

How do I open a csv/txt file from `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS`?

I have this code that worked for me when I wanted to open a picture from my photo gallery but it doesn't seem to work for CSV/TXT files.

Here's the code I'm trying out:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getFile = registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri f = result.getData().getData();
            Log.i("test", String.valueOf(f));
        }
    });

private final View.OnClickListener openFiles= v -> {
    Intent i = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
    getFile.launch(i);
};
```

The Downloads folder launches successfully and I can see my files, but when I click on it I get a popup saying "Can't open file".

I'm also not sure how to get the result file as what is returned seems to be a Uri and I don't know how to turn that into a File type.

Wondering how I can fix this.

Comment: You dont need to convert an uri to a File instance as you can open an inputstream for the uri directly. Further there is nothing in your code that tries to open a file.

Comment: @blackapps what should I add in order to open a file?

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS` [is not documented to return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager?hl=en#ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS). You should not assume that your code will work at all, across the tens of thousands of device models (with manufacturer changes).

Comment: @CommonsWare do you know what code will allow me to open download manager and let me open a file?

Comment: There is nothing like that. You can (and should) use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. The user can choose content from wherever the user wants. Use the resulting `Uri` with `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`/`openOutputStream()` to work with the chosen content.